# Error in converting byte array to int array in C#

Tags: c#, byte

I am trying to convert a byte array to an int array ad then convert the byte array back to an int array.

For converting from byte array to int array I used this code:

```
int[] iArray = new int[someSize];
byte[] bArray = new byte[iArray.Length * sizeof(int)];
Buffer.BlockCopy(iArray, 0,bArray, 0, bArray.Length); // This code works correctly.
```

But when converting from the byte array to in int array, the values in the `iArray2` array becomes false when the value in the `iArray` array is larger than 256 (may be it is overflow, I do not know.)

```
// What is the error in this code?.
int iArray2 = new int[someSize];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bArray, 0, iArray2, 0, iArray2.Length);
```

How can I convert from byte array to int array correctly?

Comment: A byte stores values from 0 to 255.  What value would you expect the resulting byte to have when converted from an integer value of, say, 1000?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Buffer.BlockCopy` always deals in *bytes*, not array units.

Therefore, when you pass `iArray2.Length` in the second `BlockCopy()` call, you're copying that many *bytes*, which is one quarter of your actual array.

Comment: @HeshamAbouelsoaod: By passing the correct length **in bytes**.